# How to start off HTML5 multiplayer (1 vs 1 game) using Websockets

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

probably had these questions a thousand times already.

For a school project I want to make a HTML5 game where you can challenge someone and play against. Now I'm pretty new to game development. I don't now exactly where to start off. There is so much information/technologies on the net that I don't know which to use. I prefer to do this in a known environment (.NET)

I found these:

- http://kaazing.com/
- http://xsockets.net/

I also checked out Node.js, socket.io, HTML5 canvas, etc

It's all a bit of overwhelming for me. :(

Comment: This is a broad question.. you need to narrow down !

Comment: Start with something much, much, much more simple. Programming is all about little successes in a row. I'd first try to implement a simple chat application using WebSockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working in a .NET environment, take a look at SignalR, http://signalr.net.  It's a very nice API around websockets (with fallbacks to other methods for older servers and browsers) that lets you do client-to-server and server-to-client communication.

Code on the client can invoke a Javascript function that will in turn invoke a method on the server.  That server method could then send a message down to one or all of the connected clients.  Alnitak's answer is correct; your communication would be from client to server to client, not directly client to client.

Comment: Thanks, I will look in to the link you gave me. Will try to do something simple first. :)

Comment: shootr.signalr.net (Built with SignalR and is Multiplayer)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a central server to relay messages between the two players.

WebSockets (and anything else you might find that plugs into a browser) are unsuitable for direct peer-to-peer communications.